# How to properly convert base64 to ArrayBuffer (images)?

Tags: javascript, image, base64, arraybuffer

First, I am using canvas to get images as ArrayBuffer and make some processing. I am doing this:

```
var buf = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data.buffer;

process(buf);
```

This does not work on images coming from domains different to the web page's due to the same origin policy.

To solve this my best bet is XMLHttpRequest. Here, I get a blob; then I use a FileReader. I can use FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer, however, I also need the dimensions of the image. For that reason I use FileReader.readAsDataURL. Once the data is read, I set the result as the src attribute of an Image object, when the image has been loaded I can get the width and height of the image.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function() {
         var image = new Image();
         image.src = this.result;
         image.onload = function() {
             var arrayBuffer = dataURItoArrayBuffer(this.src);
         }
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
}
xhr.open("GET", source);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.send();
```

As mentioned, I need the data as ArrayBuffer, so I have created a function to do so based on this [code](https://gist.github.com/fupslot/5015897) to make the convertion from base64.

```
function dataURItoArrayBuffer(dataURI) {
   // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
   // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
   var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

   // separate out the mime component
   var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

   // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
   var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
   var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
   for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
   }

   return ab;
}
```

The resulting ArrayBuffer of this function is not consistent with the dimensions of the image. For instance, an image with dimensions 32 x 32 should result in an ArrayBuffer of 3072 (32 x 32 x 3), however, the function creates an ArrayBuffer of 270, 414, or any other value unrelated to the expected one.

How can I get a consistent ArrayBuffer for that image in base64 format?
Am I missing something?

Thanks.